# Shared way of all ORM requests to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, change-tracking

i using dapper in my project and i need to use change tracker for fill automatic property and add that in the query of insert or update .

i decide create a service like change tracker for my selft but i have a question :

**Where is the passage of all requests of ORM and where can I add data to request?**

Comment: if you're using just the *core* dapper lib: then the answer is simple: "it doesn't exist" - dapper does not provide any object/change tracker etc; if you're using any of the additional bits (contrib, rainbow, etc) - you'd need to be specific, but ultimately: if you *want* that kind of feature, I'd probably say "use something like EF-Core or LLBLGenPro" (and for context: I'm the main author of Dapper)

Comment: @MarcGravell i want to crete that but i want to know where i must call that function for add to data to request ???

Comment: There is *no function* in Dapper that does that. Did you read what Marc said? You'll either need to use another library, or write that logic yourself. Dapper itself is pretty much some nice syntactic sugar around ADO.NET, it has no change tracker.